# Expect script environment variable issue

Tags: expect

I would like to receive help to resolve my expect script issue.

when I use the command "env" on my linux termial, I can see `$INFO_HME` as `/app/informatica/etldev/9.1/server`.

But i am not able to use `$INFO_HME` it in my expect script and getting error. My script shown below.

I presume, `$INFO_HME` will be replacled as `/app/informatica/etldev/9.1/server` in the `lcd` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/sftp <ID_Here>@<Host_Here> 
expect "password:" 
send "<Password_Here>\n" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "lcd $INFO_HME/infa_shared/SrcFiles\n" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "cd \"/Source/client\"\n" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "get file.csv\n"; 
expect "sftp>" 
send "quit\n"
```

Error message:

```
sftp> can't read "INFO_HME": no such variable
    while executing
"send   "lcd $INFA_HOME/infa_shared/SrcFiles\n""
    (file "Scr_Webcore_SFTP.sh" line 7)
```

Deeply appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: Can you please cross check this mistake-  as per your script send "lcd $INFO_HME/infa_shared/SrcFiles\n", I think correct variable should be $INFA_HOME. This is informatica env variable and must be setup if you have informatica up and running. The variable you can see probably some mistake.

Comment: I have checked it. There is no issue with that. The issue resolved by using the below method

Answer (score 2):

To use an env var in Expect (and Tcl) you should use `$env(VARNAME)` (or `$::env(VARNAME)` if in a function). For example:

```
[bash] # export FOO=bar
[bash] # expect -c 'puts $env(FOO)'
bar
[bash] # expect -c 'puts $::env(FOO)'
bar
[bash] #
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue seems to be fixed by using above mentioned method.